# EF4.1 based Repository and consistent view of data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, domain-driven-design

using the unit of work and repository patterns i recently came across the issue, that changes to the unit of work are not reflected to subsequent queries. Example:

```
var ctx = DIContainer.Current.Resolve<IB2bContext>();
var rep = DIContainer.Current.Resolve<IRepository<Word>>(
                new DependencyOverride<IB2bContext>(ctx));

rep.Add(new Word () { "One" };
rep.Add(new Word () { "Two" };

rep.GetAll().ToList().ForEach(i =>
                Console.Write(i.text)); // nothing seen here
```

So in other words, unless i call SaveChanges() to persist the objects into the Database, i dont see them. Well ofcause i can fiddle around with the ChangeTracker and/or do things like context.Entry(foo).Property(...).CurrentValue. But does that play with a ddd like decoupling of layers? I dont think so. And where is my consistent dataview that once was called a database transaction?

Please enlighten me.
Armin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository exposes some `GetAll` method. The method itself executes database query. If you want to see local data not inserted to database you must add them to result set. For example like:

```
public IEnumerable<Word> GetAll()
{
    DbSet<Word> set = context.Set<Word>();
    return set.AsEnumerable().Concat(set.Local);
}
```

The query execution is only responsible for returning persisted (real) data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I plainly was not aware of the Local DbSet.